# Receiving emails on Heroku

Tags: email, heroku, dns

I'm working on a web application that is going to replace an existing one. That existing one runs on another server, and its domain name is `synergy-croatia.com`. Now, I have my new application already hosted on Heroku (`synergy-croatia.herokuapp.com`), and all I need to do now is to make the domain `synergy-croatia.com` to point to my Heroku application. But there is one more thing I need to implement — you guessed — receiving emails.

I want to be able to receive emails sent to email adresses like `info@synergy-croatia.com`. So, I did a lot of Googling, and I encountered some nice solutions. But each solution implies that I have a custom domain, for which I need to set some DNS settings. I mean, I do have it (`synergy-croatia.com`), but obviously I can use it only **after** I finish my application.

Does that mean that I have to buy a domain just so I can implement receiving emails? Can I somehow set these DNS settings (`MX`es and others) directly on the Heroku subdomain? Or is there another way?

UPDATE:

One of the solutions I found was, of course, this one: http://nanceskitchen.com/2010/02/21/accept-incoming-emails-into-a-heroku-app-using-sendgrid/

But it requires a custom domain.

UPDATE 2:

This is important, I forgot to mention it. I just want these email adresses to be virtual, to forward emails to real adresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CloudMailin](http://cloudmailin.com) doesn't require you to use a 'custom domain' it gives you an email address that you can forward to, using your own domain is an optional extra. It's also available as a [Heroku addon](http://addons.heroku.com#cloudmailin). You could use this to forward your emails from any existing email server to the address that CloudMailin gives you. The original email address is also still obtainable.

Comment: Wow, that's a great idea. I knew about CloudMailin before, but I discarded it as a solution for incoming emails (since it can only forward from `@cloudmailin.org` adresses). However, it didn't come to my mind to use it for testing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you move the domain (synergy-croatia.com) to point to your Heroku application, you won't need to change the existing mail setup. You just need to set a CNAME record for www to heroku, and leave the MX (which controls the mail) in place.

If you don't have a mail solution in place, you need to look for one outside Heroku. Many domain name providers have free mail forwarding included, or you can use gmail, Outlook.com etc.